# Query to fetch counts for all the dates between the two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I am encountering a situation where, I have a data. I need to capture count of the row, project_id, for each date, within a given range of date.

e.g.: user enters date as:

```
    set @start_date = '2016-01-01';
    set @end_date   = '2016-09-30';
```

I get the data like this:

```
 |Project id|    |Tracker id| |Statusid| |Hours| |Hours| |Date Created| |Date Updated|           |Count when created|
'Cyrcle Connect', '5',        '1',       NULL, NULL, '2016-07-12 02:33:18', '2016-09-13 07:32:33', '3'
```

I have to capture information, where, I can show count for each date within these two range of date.

Desired output would be:

```
    |Count when Created|  |Count when 2016-02-10|
             3                      5
```

I know union will not work in this case, as I cannot union data for all the 12 months. User can give any range of date.

I have shown only two, but I have to capture information across all the date. The table does not have entry as it keeps the latest row. The snapshot data is available which I can workaround with to generate my sample data.

I just want to know, any method, where I can capture such information. I am not looking for complete solution, just a direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select DATE(Date_Created) as R_DATE , COUNT(*) as R_COUNT
  from <your table>
 where DATE(Date_Created) >= @Start_Date
   and DATE(Date_Created) <  @End_Date
group by R_DATE
;
```

You can also use the `between` for the time window (I prefer the above as it is clearer for me).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I thought my answer gives you what you need. What did I miss?

Comment: I will try this once again. I think, this is what I want :)

Comment: By the way, you wrote _I am not looking for complete solution, just a direction._ and I think you got it. Still, marking my answer as THE answer is your privilege, not mine.

Comment: It actually works. I was able to customize it. Thanks.